# Can a spring-boot app shuts down by itself?

Tags: linux, spring-boot

I started a spring boot app as a jar on production and on staging A. It runs for a while then suddenly it unregister JMX and shuts down . However, it doesn't fail on other environments like QA and staging B. All the environments running on linux. The command I used is

```
nohup xxx/java/java_1.8/bin/java-javaagent:xxx/monitoring/newrelic/services/xxx/newrelic.jar -Dserver.port=8201 -jar /b001/app/services/xxx/xxx.jar >> xxx/logs/xxx/xxx.log 2>&1 & port=8201
```

There are no exceptions on the log, but it appears that a shutdown hook is called. The logs contained:

`2018-12-31 14:11:01.207  INFO 7653 --- [      Thread-19] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@30c31dd7: startup date [Mon Dec 31 04:53:50 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-31 14:11:01.211  INFO 7653 --- [      Thread-19] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown`

***Application.java***

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.xxx" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.xxx")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "file:/xxx/xxx.properties", 
 ignoreResourceNotFound = true )
,@PropertySource(value = "file:xxx/xxx.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound 
 = true)
,@PropertySource(value = "application.properties")}) 
 public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

***pom.xml***

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>xxx</name>
   <description>xxx API Application</description>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
       <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20160810</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

***application.properties:***

```
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=false
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I am facing the same issue.